# Reducing to its canonical form a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, orthonormal

Let $\Phi:\mathbb{R^3}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a quadratic form represented by the matrix $B$=$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -3 & -3\\
-3 & 0 & -3\\
-3 & -3 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$. I have to find a matrix $C\in \mathrm{SO}(3)$ such that $B=C\Delta C^{-1}$, where $\Delta$ is a diagonal matrix.

What I've tried: We know that if $C\in \mathrm{SO}(3)$, then $C^{-1}=C^t$. The eigenspaces of our quadratic form (which is diagonalizable because every symmetric matrix is diagonalizable) are $V_{-6}=\mathrm{Span}((1,1,1))$ and $V_{3}=\mathrm{Span}((-1,1,0),(-1,0,1))$.

Now we know that the matrix $C^{-1}$ is a matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors of $V_{-6}$ and $V_{3}$. So, the matrix $C$ is the inverse of $C^{-1}$, with $\mathrm{det}(C)=1/3$ and $C C^{-1}=CC^t=I_{3}$.

The last point of this exercise is to find a basis that reduces $\Phi$ to its canonical form. In any case I solved this, I made lot of confusion but now it's all clear.

Comment: You lost me with that $\;\phi-orthogonal\;$ ...are you *trying* to define an inner product wrt the matrix $\;B\;$ ? Because it can't be done as $\;B\;$ isn't positive definite...Thus, I assume you have the usual inner product in $\;\Bbb R^3\;$ and thus the eigenvectors of different eigenvalues are not only linearly independent but in fact orthoganl to each other. Thus, you only need to orthonormalize some eigenvalue of $\;\lambda=-6\;$ and carry on Gram-Schmidt on two lin. indep. eigenvalues of $\;\lambda=-3\;$ ...and you're done. Did I miss something?

Comment: Suuure. I made confusion, now I edit my question. If it is not a problem let me know what you think after the correction.

Comment: It looks fine...but I can't see any question. You now take the matrix $\;C\;$ whose columns are that orthonormal basis and that's all.

Comment: In the first part I have to find a special orthogonal matrix. In my case $C$ has determinant $1/3$, so I should multiply the matrix for $3$. But if I do that I don't get the identity by $C C^{-1}$.

Comment: C isn’t orthogonal, because vectors of $V_{3}$ aren’t orthogonal to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you did but perhaps you did Gramn Schmidt to **all** the vectors and this screws orthogonality must of the times.

You take $\;u_1=\frac1{\sqrt3}(1,1,1)=\;$  an orthonormal basis of $\;V_{-6}\;$ , and then you apply GS on the basis of $\;V_{-3}\;$, obtaining

$$u_2=\frac1{\sqrt2}(-1,0,1)\;,\;\;\frac1{\sqrt6}(-1,2,-1)$$

and now you can chech $\;\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}\;$ is an *orthonormal basis* and with it you can construct your $\;C\;$ , and orthogonal matrix.

The above is specially easy because of what I commented before: $\;V_{-3}\perp V_{-6}\;$ ...